# Why are researchers at some think tanks titled professor?

Tags: titles, academic-history

Within my own discipline one of the best examples of this may be at the [Santa Fe Institute](https://www.santafe.edu/people/type/researcher?groups__in=1), but I've seen this other places as well. Quite simply, why are researchers at some think tanks titled "professor" when they don't have a university affiliation?

Comment: Because there are no laws against it?

Comment: There are many PhD holders who work in the industry but have significant contributions either through publications, service, committee work etc. I guess it is a matter of prestige?

Comment: @PeterShor ...in the US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "professor" is most often used by universities, but the *content* of the word more generally refers to a person whose job is some mixture of higher-level education and research.

Thus, while it is unusual for a place like the Santa Fe Institute to call some of their employees professors, I would judge it to be a reasonable description of their work given that the institute is well-respected in the academic world as both an educational and research institution.

Most other industry or "think tank" organizations do not have a similar mission and it would thus be less appropriate for them to give such a title to their staff.